# How to get Call UI Presentation using ConnectionService

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use ConnectionService to present the ConnectionService provided call UI from an FCM notification. What am I missing to accomplish this? Following the steps on https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged I've added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_OWN_CALLS"/>
```

and

```
<service android:name=".SparrowConnectionService"
    android:label="@string/connection_service_label"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.telecom.ConnectionService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

When I receive my FCM notification, I do:

```
TelecomManager telecomManager = (TelecomManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
String packageName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
String className = SparrowConnectionService.class.getName();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(packageName, className);
PhoneAccountHandle accountHandle= new PhoneAccountHandle(componentName, "testID");

PhoneAccount account = PhoneAccount.builder(accountHandle, getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.connection_service_label))
        .setCapabilities(PhoneAccount.CAPABILITY_SELF_MANAGED)
        .build();
telecomManager.registerPhoneAccount(account);

Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putParcelable(TelecomManager.EXTRA_PHONE_ACCOUNT_HANDLE, accountHandle);
extras.putInt(TelecomManager.EXTRA_START_CALL_WITH_VIDEO_STATE, VideoProfile.STATE_BIDIRECTIONAL);
telecomManager.addNewIncomingCall(accountHandle, extras);
```

Which successfully triggers my ConnectService's onCreateIncomingConnection method (CallConnection extends Connection)

```
@Override
public Connection onCreateIncomingConnection(PhoneAccountHandle connectionManagerPhoneAccount, ConnectionRequest request) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateIncomingConnection");
    CallConnection connection = new CallConnection(getApplicationContext());
    connection.setConnectionProperties(Connection.PROPERTY_SELF_MANAGED);
    connection.setCallerDisplayName("TestID", TelecomManager.PRESENTATION_ALLOWED);

    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putBoolean(Connection.EXTRA_ANSWERING_DROPS_FG_CALL, true);
    extras.putString(Connection.EXTRA_CALL_SUBJECT, "Test call subject text");
    connection.putExtras(extras);
    return connection;
}
```

This calls my CallConnection's onShowIncomingCallUi method but displays no UI. How can I display the UI?

Comment: Do you want to show your own UI, or do you want to show the system UI?

Answer (score 0):

You need to show your incoming call UI in the onShowIncomingCallUi method.
The self-managed ConnectionService API is intended for calling apps which want to provide their own complete UI for calling, but still want to coexist with mobile calls in Android.

Comment: In my case, this method just does not called by the system.